# how to use notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, adapter

Hi i have problem with my adapter, i don't know how to refresh my data in ListView when i use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after data changing nothing happen. I wonder if i have to override `notifyDataSetChanged()` in this class. I hope you will help me.
Here is my adapter class:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
    public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
    public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);

            txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
            txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
            txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
            txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);

        }

        HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

here im adding my fragment class which use this adapter:

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
    public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
    public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";
    public ListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spolki_portfel, container, false);

            ListView listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View header = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.naglowek_wlasne_spolki, listView, false);
            listView.addHeaderView(header);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.size();i++){
            dodaj_spolke(MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).nazwa,MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).wartosc_aktualna,MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).ilosc,MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(i).cena_kupna);
        }

            adapter=new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), list);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            //THIS INCREASE VALUE
            MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(0).cena_kupna++;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            //CHECKING IF VALUE IS HIGHER
            System.out.println("cena " + MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(0).cena_kupna);

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to override `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Can you post a code snippet of where you're using the adapter?

Comment: You dont have to implement notifyDataSetChanged yourself. Have you verified that your data is actually changing? It's easy to get mixed up with that List of HashMaps that you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but you're probably not actually updating the adapter's list. Make a method in your adapter that looks like this

```
public void updateItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newList) {
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(newList);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call this from wherever you have the adapter set up

```
mAdapter.updateItems(newList)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem might be because you don't have the right Adapter class. Try this one, I didn't had time to test it but it should work, also call notifiyDataSetChanged() after adding new elements to that list.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
private Activity activity;
public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";


public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super(activity, R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, list);
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
        listViewHolder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
        listViewHolder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
        listViewHolder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
        listViewHolder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    listViewHolder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}

public class ListViewHolder {
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
}

}
```

Comment: when i use your code i get error with `public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}` eclipse suggest me to change return type.

Comment: sorry didn't checked that method, change Object with HashMap<String, String> so it should return the exact type of the items in your list

Answer (score -1):

Ok, im sorry for wasting your time it was my fault i missed that i was changing source of data but no exacly ListView I should change `list.get(0).put("Fourth", "5");` but i was changing `MainActivity.zmienne.lista_moich_spolek.get(0).cena_kupna++;` and I wondered why it didn't work.